# Is is possible to access views from a module file?

Tags: 7, theming, views

I have created a view in drupal. My question is, is it possible to access the contents of the view or value stored in the view from the module file..
Need any details or code plss comment.

Comment: It's not appropriate to ask us to write your code for you - please update the question with the research you've already done, the code you've tried yourself, and what didn't work/error messages. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use drupal function
 `views_get_view_result($name, $display_id = NULL)`

**$name** : name of the view 
**$display_id** : On the edit page for the view in question, you'll find a list of displays at the left side of the control area . e.g. 'MASTER', 'Page'

This function will return **An array containing an object for each view item.**

Reference :https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

Comment: can we access it in a custom module??

Comment: Yes you can access it in custom module.

Comment: should i add it as a hook in my custom module??. can u please elaborate

Comment: Where do u want to use the function?

Comment: in my custom .module file....

Comment: @Ajmal Please make some effort to solve the problem yourself; update your question with the code you've tried, what you expect to happen, what did happen, and any error messages you receive. As it is the question is dangerously close to being closed as we specifically don't provide tutorials in response to vague requests, and don't operate a support forum. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Clive, really I'm not expecting a coding for this question.I have tried some confusing stuffs which may deviate the visitors answering this question. In order to be crisp and clear I asked this question without coding, I need to know whether it was possible or not??. have anyone tried it before??. this is what I need from this question. Please apologize me if I have talked anything wrong...